# M1 Chip - Maven Java project failing to deploy on AWS Copilot

Tags: java, docker, maven, apple-m1, aws-copilot

I am trying to deploy a maven project Backend Service within my engine using AWS copilot. The maven backend service is failing to deploy with the following error being the most detailed I can find on cloud watch logs:

`copilot/export/58577c160d standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: exec format error`

Looking online, I believe this is an architecture issue. I have encountered this problem before and it was fixed by changing a GraphQl image from FROM hasura/graphql-engine:v2.1.1.cli-migrations-v3 to FROM hasura/graphql-engine:v2.0.7 time so I'll play about with images again, would be keen to know you have any more insight into this error as I keep bumping into it on AWS copilot.

The images I am using for service failing to deploy are :
`FROM maven:3.8.3-openjdk-17-slim AS build`
`FROM openjdk:17-slim`

Full issue here: https://jackow98.notion.site/Copilot-failing-to-deploy-def6f6281c794e97b1cb3ae4ece964bd

Any advice on how to fix the error for Maven would be much appreciated!

Comment: The error is related to an go code which looks like not being built for a particular platform. That looks not related to Maven...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are on an M1 machine?

If so, try adding `platform: linux/arm64` to your workload manifest. (See https://aws.github.io/copilot-cli/docs/manifest/backend-service/#platform.)

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer

Looking into this further, it definitely is an M1 problem. Can deploy on my windows machine using WSL not problem.

I tried adding in `platform: linux/arm64` to the manifest file however I am presented with the following error `validate manifest against environment test: validate ARM: 'Fargate Spot' is not supported when deploying on ARM architecture`

Comment: Unfortunately, Spot is not yet supported for ARM, but it is in the works!